# nativescript iOS Cocoa Pods build error

Tags: nativescript

I recently started getting a weird error when I try to run my app in VS Code:

WARNING]:     WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
[31;1mProcessing node_modules failed. Exception: Pod install command failed. Error output:
   Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[NSDebugAdapter] The tns command finished its execution with code 127.

Has anyone seen that?  I see the suggested action message, but I have no idea where ./profile is?

I am using tns version 2.5.0 and VS Code on El Capitan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was solved by opening the bash profile (open ~/.bash_profile) and adding `EXPORT LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Thanks @NickIliev from Telerik for the suggestion.  See 
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3659 for more details.

Comment: one fix: there should be 'export' instead of 'EXPORT'.

Comment: Yes its work after adding this "EXPORT LANG=en_US.UTF-8"  line in ~/.bash_profile and restart your developing tool like android studio or Visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the deployment_target it defaults to 8.0
If one of the Pods require higher version of IOS, It prints out this error.
I recommend going to your IOS folder and run pod deintegrate and then run pod install to see the actual error.